# react virtualize table - have bad performance

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-virtualized

I am using react virtualize table with many sub components in it and have very bad performance when rendering it.
it gets more aweful after scrolling, clicking buttons...

```
<TableContainer className={classes.table}>
    <AutoSizer> 
      {({ height, width }) => (
        <Table
          height={height}
          width={width}
          rowHeight={64}
          headerHeight={84}
          rowCount={!isLoading ? tableRowsData.length : LOADING_ROWS_COUNT}
          gridStyle={{
            direction: 'inherit',
          }}
          rowGetter={({ index }) => getRowRow(index)}
          className={classes.table}
          rowClassName={getRowClassName}
          noRowsRenderer={noRowsRendererHandler}
          disableHeader={showEmptyState}
        >
          {Object.keys(headersConfig).map((key) => {
            return (
              <Column
                key={key}
                headerRenderer={({dataKey}) => headersConfig[dataKey].content}
                cellRenderer={({ cellData }) => cellData}
                dataKey={key}
                width={headersConfig[key].width}
              />
            )
          })}
        </Table>
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
  </TableContainer>
```

the headerConfig is an object with all the column components.
how can I use this table wiser? how can I prevent many unnecessary re-renders?
am I need to use the rowRenderer prop? if so, can I get an example or a link to understand the implementation?
tnx
cheers

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev tools' profiler to see where time is being spent? Or React's dev tools?

Comment: does someone has an example with rowRenderer use in react virtualize table?